# IsValidated not working with redux in react stepzilla

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-stepzilla

I developed the multistep registration form using react-stepzilla.I am using react and redux in this registration.

I need to validate the steps and i followed these steps to add the validation to the steps

1. I added the isValidated function to the step.
2. It is working in react but it is not working in redux with react may be react-stepzilla is problem with HOC.
3. I followed the react-stepzilla module git solutions but i got the error 
   "main.js:318 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isValidated' of undefined"

```js
//React stepzilla main component

const steps = [
 { name: 'step1', component: <RegistrationType /> },
 { name: 'step2', component: <PersonalDetails /> },
 { name: 'step3', component: <ContactDetails /> }
]

class MultiStep extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <Fragment>
    <h1 className="page-header">Register for New Account</h1>
    <StepZilla
     steps={steps}
     stepsNavigation={true}
     nextButtonText='Save and Continue'
     backButtonText='Back'
     nextButtonCls="btn btn-warning active pull-right mr-0"
     backButtonCls="btn btn-primary pull-left ml-25"
          hocValidationAppliedTo= {[0,1, 2]}
    />

   </Fragment>
  );
 }
}
```

```js
//Step1 Component:


// Checking the validation for registration
 isValidated(){
  alert("checking isValidated calling")
  return this.state.count > 2
 }
  
 // connecting with redux 
 export default  connect((state) => ({register_reducer: state.register_reducer.register_user}),{saveUser})(Step1); //This is not working and getting the error 
 
 //connecting without redux
 export default Step1 // this is working and checking the validation part
```

I got the error "Cannot read property 'isValidated' of undefined" when we are connected with redux.
[image]

Please help me out of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your function

```
function isValidated(){
    alert("checking isValidated calling")
    return this.state.count > 2
}
```

you need to add `function` before your function name.

And if it is ES6

```
const isValidated = () => { }
```

Answer (score 0):

It just works without connecting Redux due to `connect()` function always return a **new** Component and it will not have `isValidated` method you wrote.

You can use `connect()` function at `MultiStep` component and pass `props` to child components. You can see my code:

```
...

class MultiStep extends Component {
    render() {
        const {example} = this.props

        const steps = [
            { name: 'step1', component: <RegistrationType {...example} /> },
            { name: 'step2', component: <PersonalDetails /> },
            { name: 'step3', component: <ContactDetails /> }
        ]

        return (
            <Fragment>
                <h1 className="page-header">Register for New Account</h1>
                <StepZilla
                    steps={steps}
                    stepsNavigation={true}
                    nextButtonText='Save and Continue'
                    backButtonText='Back'
                    nextButtonCls="btn btn-warning active pull-right mr-0"
                    backButtonCls="btn btn-primary pull-left ml-25"
          hocValidationAppliedTo= {[0,1, 2]}
                />

            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}
..
...

export connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MultiStep)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this, send props to your steps rather than using redux connect. this is extra long code but it may help some, understand what is happening.

```
    class MultiStep extends Component {
      render() {

        const steps = [
          { name: "General Info", component: <StepOne {...this.props} /> },
          { name: "Personal Info", component: <StepTwo {...this.props} /> },
          { name: "Educational Info", component: <StepThree {...this.props} /> },
          { name: "Address", component: <StepFour {...this.props} /> },
          { name: "Account Info", component: <StepFive {...this.props} /> },
          { name: "Review", component: <StepSix {...this.props} /> },
          { name: "Done", component: <StepSix {...this.props} /> }
        ];

        return (
          <StepZilla
            steps={steps}
            stepsNavigation={true}
            nextButtonText="Save and Continue"
            backButtonText="Back"
            //hocValidationAppliedTo={[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]} //commenting this worked for me.
            nextButtonCls="btn btn-prev pull-right nextBtn btn-color"
            backButtonCls="btn btn-next btn-color"
          />
        );
      }
    }

    // export default MultiStep;
    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      errors: state.errors
    });

    const mapDispatchToProps = {
      setGeneralInfo,
   };

    export default connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      mapDispatchToProps
    )(MultiStep);
```

and in the steps you can write your isValidated method in your component.

```
  isValidated = () => {
    const genInfo = {
      employee_name: this.state.employee_name,
      employee_code: this.state.employee_code,
      employee_email: this.state.employee_email,
      password: this.state.password,
   };
    console.log(genInfo);
    this.props.setGeneralInfo(genInfo, this.props.jumpToStep);
    return false; // make it return false. just in case. lol

  };
```

and in your action

```
export const setGeneralInfo = (generalDetails, jumpToStep) => dispatch => {
  console.log("gen details:", generalDetails);
  Api.setGeneralInfo(generalDetails)
    .then(res => {
      console.log("res gen details:", res);
      jumpToStep(1); //<<<< JUMP STEPS FROM HERE <STEPS START FROM 0>

      return dispatch({
        type: SET_GENERAL_INFO,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      //jumpToStep(0);
      console.log("err gen details:", err.response);
      return dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      });
    });
};
```